# How to find an area of right triangle?

Tags: triangles, area

I'm really new in math, and I need your help. I've been searching for some formulas to calculate an area of this triangle:
[triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04d5E.png)

I couldn't find anything. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you know about sines and cosines? The sum of the angles of a triangle? Any special facts about right-angled triangles?

Comment: I don't really know how to use sines and cosines. But I know Heron's formula and Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use that $$A=\frac{1}{2}H\cdot x$$ and $x$ is given by $$H\cdot \tan(60^{\circ})=x$$

Comment: Thank you. That worked! I'm gonna learn these stuff (sin, cos, tag) today!